# Spring - JDBC - SQL Server - Can't get access to database - normal jdbc access works

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

So I implemented jdbc in my java programm. The "old-fashion" way works fluently and i get access to the database. 
Now I wanted to refactor my code to Spring JDBC, because it offers more opportunities. But somehow my injection from beans.xml does not work. The dataSource is always null, therefore I can't execute any SQL Querys... because it is always null.

**Beans.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userService" class="beco.webservice.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userDAO" class="beco.webservice.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**database.properties**

```
db.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://XX-XXXXXX\\XXXXX;databaseName=BBSupportQA;integratedSecurity=true
```

**UserDataAccessObject.java**

```java
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import beco.webservice.dao.UserDAO;
import beco.webservice.model.User;

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void createUser(User user) {
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.BCO_Person(USER_ID, Email, Nickname) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        int update = jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, user.getUserId(), user.getEmail(), user.getNickname());
        if(update>0)
            System.out.print("User is created...");
    }
[...]
}
```

So I always get a Nullpointer and i debugged it and saw that DataSource / JDBCTemplate is always null.

If i use the old fashion way:

```java
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:sqlserver://XX-XXXXXX\\XXXXX;databaseName=BBSupportQA;integratedSecurity=true");
    System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Database successfully connected.");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works without any problems. What am I doing wrong? Is the url schema in the Spring properties different from the normal jdbc? I have no explanation for this.

Comment: what happens if you use a debug break point inside setDataSource()? Is it called?

Comment: Yes it is called, both are null

Comment: Is the datasouce initilized at all? What if you add a breakpoint on beginning of DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName() or the constructor.

Comment: DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(String driverName) is called with the correct string. But what i noticed is, that only the empty constructor is called
    DriverManagerDataSource(){

    }

But the constructor with DriverManagerDataSource(String url) or (String url, Properties conProps) is not called

Comment: Have you configured your dao classes as components @components ?

Comment: No, should I do this?

Comment: Actually your dao can't locate your database.properties and returns null.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582762/include-database-properties-from-spring-project-into-web-xml

Comment: Hm. I think the setup you have here should have worked. Are you autowiring something? Or creating UserDAOImpl with some other config? Or using any annotation based configuration? I see you have imported import `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;`

Comment: No i am wiring nothing, at one point I tried to autowire something, but deleted it afterwards, so it just an import, which is unused. 
As you can see in the beam.xml I instanced UserDAOimpl in the xml file. 

@georgesvan but if I check the values, even though its null, the url for example is in the "object". So it loads the database.properties. I also had the values hardcoded in the beam.xml. and it doesnt work

Comment: I think you should take some time to read the official spring data access guide : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Comment: okay thank you. It really drives me crazy, since 1 1/2 days I cant fix it. I dont want to go back to old fashion jdbc style. Even if I type in a completely wrong db.url I still get a nullpointer on the object. Is there a way to figure out whether the connection is applied and working?

Comment: You can add a breakpoint in the setUrl() of DriverManagerDataSource and step until it is created and configured. When you know it is properly configured, you can call getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(sql) from the debugger to query the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just set it up again (everything the same in my opinion) and now it worked. no clue why it wasnt working before... Thanks for the help though